# How to load coredumps in mac osx?

Tags: c, macos, gdb

I'm trying to learn how to use gdb (tutorial: [https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~learn/debugging/modules/gdb_coredumps/](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Elearn/debugging/modules/gdb_coredumps/)). I'm on mac os x, 10.14, mojave.

Here's a repro:

```
ulimit -c
unlimited
```

```
gcc -g -o broken_linked_list broken_linked_list.c
```

```
./broken_linked_list
[1]    10585 segmentation fault  ./broken_linked_list
```

```
gdb broken_linked_list /cores/core.14192
```

Error

```
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from broken_linked_list...
Reading symbols from /Users/me/foo/broken_linked_list.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/broken_linked_list...
"/cores/core.14192": no core file handler recognizes format
```

Comment: Have you tried `lldb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb` doesn't understand macOS MachO binaries. Use `lldb`:

```
> gdb -c /cores/core.782 a.out
...
"/cores/core.782": Core file format not supported
(gdb) quit
> lldb -c /cores/core.782 a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out" --core "/cores/core.782"
Core file '/cores/core.782' (x86_64) was loaded.

(lldb) bt
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100019062 a.out`main + 258
    frame #1: 0x00007fff2059ff3d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #2: 0x00007fff2059ff3d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```